# What is the missing word?

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

On the roadside last week, I found what appears to be a page from a farmer's journal. Although the spelling and grammar might not be 100% correct, I can easily read *all but one word of it*. There is a hole in the paper (shown as a blank line below) where that missing word was, and just for fun, I have been trying to figure out what it was.

I am fairly certain that the word is a number, because all of the other numbers on the page were circled, and there was also a circle around the missing word.

Apparently, he split up each day's entry with horizontal lines.

Here is the page:

> Aah, life in the city of Emory! We know of no web access. We do need it soon. Got to go...

---

> Some guy fed ________ old eggs to my pig. First, we do urge him to NOT
>   feed my pig. My, oh, my, he aims to annoy us, as he bent the alloy
>   pole below the coop roof! My wife almost told him to chill. Oh, how
>   she abhors to be wronged!

---

> Now we do see an old gipsy tie his one cow up at the billowy, old elm
>   tree by the fir tree, as we begin to accost the guy to buy feed. His
>   red chow feed bin sold for one cent! We got one as the guy spoke: "Hi!
>   We fry the best yucca in the city- the cost- one cent too!"

---

> First, we chop wood, fix the ox yoke, fry the berry pie, mop the
>   floors.... "The ghost" spooked my wife, "Boo!" So, my wife got the
>   chills. She got the gist of his song.

---

**What is the missing word?**

Comment: Things that come to my mind: acronyms, anagrams, mnemonics for mathematical constants, palindromes. None of these seems to work though.

Comment: @randal'thor: It's not Scrabble scores, either ...

Comment: I like this puzzle, but it would be nice to find a way to incorporate the hint instead of having it as an 'extra'. With the puzzle alone, there are other words (like 'my' or 'his') that fit.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The missing word is:

> forty

It is the only number that fits into the pattern exhibited by the diary entries:

> The words in the text are either alphabetically increasing or decreasing. Increasing means each letter in a word comes after the previous one in the alphabet (B ≤ E ≤ S ≤ T) and decreasing that it comes before the previous letter (P ≥ I ≥ G). The sequences are not strict, so double letters are allowed. Increasing and decreasing words alternate, so we need an increasing number. We are told that the missing word is a number and forty is the only one that fits the bill.